# Can't center a zurb foundation callout

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

This is probably boneheadedly easy, but I've tried a lot of different approaches and cannot get this bloody callout to center.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 small-12 center columns">
        <div class="radius panel large-4 small-4 columns">
            <div class="row"><input id="loginUserInput" name="loginUserInput" type="text" value="Username" /></div>
            <div class="row"><input id="loginPasswordInput" name="loginPasswordInput" type="password" value="Password" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.center {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sgwtd/

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle of your problem as it works fine for me - http://jsfiddle.net/KFRq3/

Comment: That is a _seriously_ ugly JSFiddle

Comment: lol, wasn't sure how else to include foundation

Comment: @LynnOwens did you solve this issue with CSS? There's a foundation way of doing it, without additional styles, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to center that callout the foundation way, since you are already using it, then `large-centered` is your friend

```
<div class="radius panel large-4 small-4 columns large-centered">
```

If you want it centered in both desktop and mobile views then you can add `small-centered`

```
<div class="radius panel large-4 small-4 columns small-centered large-centered">
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd rather not mix a framework with straight css.  This works great.  I appreciate it, Von.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
float:none;
margin: auto;
```

to the callout's element `<div class="radius panel large-4 small-4 columns">`

There is a foundation media query that is floating it left. You might even wan to add an ID to that div and add the above styles to that instead, to prevent overwriting any potential occurrences of that which are supposed to be floated.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `.center` can align only text, but as i see, in your div you have two another divs with `row` classes and input-fields inside.
So, if you want to align your input-fields centered - you need to change your

```
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

to

```
 .center {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
     }
```

Hope i understand you correctly.

Comment: I need the callout div to be centered.  Unfortunately this solution doesn't help, but it was a great point.  I'll add margin:auto to my center class.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your stylesheet:

```
.center .panel { 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    float: none; 
}
```

You have to disable the float that is applied to the `.columns` class in order for `margin: 0 auto;` to work as expected.